# JQuery 1.4.4 disabled not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add and remove disabled property from input elements but prop or attr is not working. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sak1o3yj/)

I have tried this but nothing works

```
    $('.disabledCheckboxes').prop("disabled", false); // Enable all
$('.disabledCheckboxes').prop("disabled", true); // Re-disable all
    $('.disabledCheckboxes').attr("disabled"); // Re-disable all
$('.disabledCheckboxes').removeAttr("disabled"); // Enable all
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/prop/ wasn't added till 1.6

Comment: Your fiddle appears to have an issue loading jQuery 1.4. Using a CDN it works fine with attr https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Lee1jbkv/

Comment: I have an old codebase which is heavily dependent on .live() . Is there any solution to add and remove disabled property from input box

Comment: yes, .attr, the commented out version in your fiddle.

Comment: @Richard Consider accepting my answer if it helped please.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was actually working. You were not referencing Jquery in your fiddle. 
So this is fine:

```
$('.disabledCheckboxes').prop("disabled", false); // Enable all
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/tnczy1v8/1/)

**UPDATE:** As mentioned by KevinB, `prop` wasn't added until jQuery 1.6, so if you really need to use jQuery 1.4.4, use `attr`, like so:

```
$('.disabledCheckboxes').attr("disabled", false); // Enable all
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/dx5yv19w/)

Comment: this won't work in jQuery 1.4.4 (though the code he has commented out will)

Comment: @KevinB My bad, didn't see the mention of jQuery 1.4.4 Updated.

Comment: The code he has already works fine, he was only having an issue with jsFiddle not loading the version of jQuery he needed.